# VB.net modify a textfile by using listbox and textbox

Tags: vb.net, text, textbox, listbox

I want to be able to edit/delete/insert lines of text from a textfile by using listbox and textbox.

I want to display all the contents of the textfile per line in a listbox and when I click a line of text it will then display it in the textbox giving me the option to either edit or delete that line of text.

My insertion of text would be inserted after the last line of text being displayed in the listbox. Is this possible? I just want a starting point and I will continue it from there. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately, StackOverflow is based around helping developers once they've already reached their starting point. I suggest trying something, and then asking questions when you've made some basic progress and have code to show.

Comment: I don't get it. You mean you want a text editor with real-time edit/delete/insert? Why not delete and add?

Comment: I will be writing a code moments from now. I am sorry about my approach. Will be updating my post if ever i would encounter any problems during my coding. Thanks.

Comment: No user is going to enjoy that UI.  Just put the text in a TextBox that has its Multiline property set to True.  And a Save button that writes it back.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer with a listview , button 9 is to fill Listview, listview click sends the text to textbox and button 10 saves it back to the listview

This is probably the simplest way to do what you want to achieve.

```
Private Sub Button9_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button9.Click

    ListView1.HeaderStyle = ColumnHeaderStyle.None
    ListView1.HideSelection = False

    For i As Integer = 0 To 50
        ListView1.Items.Add("Line number" & i.ToString)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub ListView1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListView1.Click

    TextBox8.Text = ListView1.SelectedItems(0).Text

End Sub

Private Sub Button10_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button10.Click

    ListView1.SelectedItems(0).Text = TextBox8.Text

End Sub
```

Probably a good starting point for you anyway and expand this code from here on.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is possible. I would suggest to use already existing text editors rather than re-inventing the wheel. If you still want to go ahead and create a new one from start, then you can try the following.

1. Create a window form application in vb.net with ListBox control for showing the lines, a textbox control for entering the file name, a button to browse to the given file, a button on clicking on which the file content should get loaded. Refer file objects for this.
2. Utilise ContextMenu class in vb.net to allow right click to read selected listbox line and accordingly perform add/delete/edit operation by modifying the selected listitem value.